# Java map.copyOf not using source map comparator

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, copy, comparator

I have innumerable maps with custom keys and comparators. I have noticed that the when I create a map using code like

```
    var map = TreeMap<>( someCustomComparator );
```

And then later I create an immutable (and small and fast) copy of it using code like:

```
    map = Map.copyOf( map );
```

Then `map.get( similarObject )` then fails to retrieve `someObject`, even when `someObject` and `similarObject` compare equal ("have the same equivalence class") under the comparator `someCustomComparator`.

Debugging into the API I find that `Map.copyOf` returns a map implementation that uses `Object::equals` to compare keys, i.e. it does not use the comparator used to construct the original map (in my example this would be `someCustomComparator`). Obviously when `someObject` and `similarObject` are not the same object but have the same equivalence class under `someCustomComparator` but `Object::equals` is not overridden, this then yields the bizarre result that

```
    map.get( similarObject ) ==> someObject
```

before the `map = Map.copyOf( map )` instruction, and

```
    map.get( similarObject ) ==> null
```

after the `map = Map.copyOf( map )` instruction. Is this expected behaviour I have to live with or should I report a Java defect ?

(Note that the class of `some/similarObject` also implements `comparable`, and that is also ignored by the `Map.copyOf` implementation.)

(I presume this behaviour is common across all the collection copyOf implementations.)

Comment: Hi & Welcome! [`new TreeMap<K, V>(SortedMap<K, ? extends V> oldMap);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.SortedMap)) is (type and sort) safer!

Comment: Hi. I am not sure I understand "type safer", since TreeMap implements Navigable map which implements Map, which is anyway returned by Map.copyOf, all <K,V>. Sort-safer, clearly, that is the premise of this question. In fact the original maps are all TreeMap with custom comparators, but once the maps and their content have been built, they are immutable, hence it makes sense to seek a more compact, faster implementation. See below for more comments on sort.

Comment: A `java.util.Map` has no "order" ..it has only keys and values... For order you need a (more specific) `java.util.SortedMap` ..at least

Comment: See below response and analysis for the implications of the specification of Map.

Answer (score 4):

The specification for the [`copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) method states

> Returns an unmodifiable Map **containing the entries of the given Map**.

(emphasis mine)

Which means only the entries get copied, nothing else. Hence, it is expected behavior, not a bug.

On the other hand, as suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74040214/java-map-copyof-not-using-source-map-comparator#comment130730280_74040214), the documentation for the constructor of the `TreeMap` class says

> Constructs a new tree map containing the same mappings and using the same ordering as the specified sorted map. This method runs in linear time.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `m` - the sorted map whose mappings are to be placed in this map, **and whose comparator is to be used to sort this map**

(again, emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Federico said in his answer, the Javadoc of `Map` also says this in the "Unmodifiable Maps" section:

> - The iteration order of mappings is unspecified and is subject to change.

If you need an unmodifiable map that uses the same order, wrap the map using `Collections.unmodifiableMap`. If you want a copy, just create a new `TreeMap` as Federico said:

```java
private static <K, V> SortedMap<K, V> copyOf(SortedMap<K, V> map) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSortedMap(new TreeMap<>(map));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the the definition of what constitutes an equivalence class is different between Map and SortedMap in a way that appears likely to lead to defects, see below.

Comment: There is another option that you can use if you need to use `equals`, and that is to copy the `SortedMap` into a `LinkedHashMap`: `Collections.unmodifiableMap(new LinkedHashMap<>(map))`. The result is no longer a `SortedMap` but a regular `Map`, but it does preserve insertion order, which is the order provided by the original `SortedMap`.

Answer (score 1):

In the API specification of `Map`, `Map.get(Object key)` states:

*"More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that `Objects.equals(key, k)`, then this method returns `v`; otherwise it returns `null`. (There can be at most one such mapping.)"*

And the API specification of `SortedMap` states:

*"All keys inserted into a sorted map must implement the `Comparable` interface (or be accepted by the specified comparator)"* and

*"Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted map (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the sorted map is to correctly implement the `Map` interface."*

It is this latter paragraph that I had forgotten when I posted this question. Hence, the above behaviour mentioned in the question is expected, even if it is bizarre. So To get consistent behaviour between `Map` and `SortedMap` `Object::equals` must be overridden to be consistent with the `Comparable` or `Comparator`, whichever is being used.

This is quite a serious requirement / restriction because it means that you should only ever use maps with comparators in combination with keys where the key's implementation overrides `Object::equals` to be consistent with the bespoke comparator's version of equals. I.e. in principle for every bespoke comparator there should be a corresponding bespoke key. I think this point is easily missed; I certainly missed it.

A corollary of this requirement is that objects that are not specifically designed as bespoke keys for some bespoke comparator cannot in general  be used as keys for a map with a bespoke comparator (something/anything inheriting `SortedMap`) since in general the map will break the contract for `Map`. I find this whole situation problematic. I think it would be more consistent to utilise the following comparison hierarchy for all maps (including `Map`):

- If present, `Comparator<T>`, else
- if defined for the supplied key type, `Comparable<T>`, else
- if overridden for the supplied key type, `Object::equals`, else
- use the default `Object::equals`, i.e. `==`.

I.e. if a comparator has been supplied to a map, use it, otherwise if the key is comparable, use that, otherwise use the key's `equal(Object)` method, the default implementation of which is `==`. Implementations of `Map` that do not permit bespoke comparators (effectively anything that is NOT a `SortedMap`) would need to accept comparators (and use `Comparable<T>` where available when a comparator is not supplied) for the purpose of defining equivalence classes (not for ordering). For this purpose it might be useful to define the concept of an "`Equalator<T>`", or "`Equivalencer<T>`" to provide the necessary bespoke definition of equals (equivalence) for keys of type `T` present in some `Map`. This avoids the need to define a sort order for maps that don't require it / don't accept bespoke sort orders. Comparators could be modified to inherit `Equalator<T>` to provide explicit equivalence as well as a sort order (`Comparator<T>` in general implies an implicit definition of equivalence anyway).

This change to the `Map` API specification would avoid the need to define a bespoke key for every comparator for `SortedMap`s, and allow the use of general objects as keys without breaking the contract for `Map`. It would also mean that the same object type could be used as a key in different `Map`s while utilising different definitions of equivalence, something which is not easily possible at the moment since `Map` is restricted to using `Object::equals` to define equivalence.

I don't have a use case for different equivalence classes with unsorted maps, but I have a large number of use cases for bespoke comparators, sometimes with and sometimes without bespoke keys, and it is problematic that I need to define both a comparator for the map and a consistent `Object::equals` in the associated key. The comparator should, in my opinion, be sufficient. Forgetting to define, or making a definition of `Object::equals` inconsistent with a map's comparator leads all too easily to weird defects that can manifest far away from the cause and require API debugging to understand.

Comment: You've identified the main issue. To copy mappings from a `TreeMap` with a custom comparator to a map like `HashMap` or `Map.copyOf` you need to provide `hashCode` and `equals` methods that define the same equivalence class as `compare(a,b)==0`. The specification does have some oblique words around "consistent with equals" but in general it needs to do a much better job at this. (There are also some outright bugs, for example, `TreeSet.add()` says that it uses `equals()` but it does not.) Unfortunately the `Map` (and `Set`) interfaces are unlikely to be evolved in the way you suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your response Stuart. Presumably I am stepping into some linguistic horrors I don't understand that make such changes very difficult, or this sort of thing is understandably far down the priority list. In any case, something to be inserted into every Java for beginners course 8- )